# A Map of Different Function Types in Scala

Tags: scala

I have two functions with different type signatures, and I want to store them both in a Map:

```
val add = ((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b)
val odd = ((a: Int) => a % 2 == 0)

var funcs = Map[String, Any]("add" -> add, "odd" -> odd)
```

Then I want to access these functions at a later date, without having to know about their types. How would I do this? I can write:

```
funcs("add").asInstanceOf[(Int, Int) => Int](1, 2)
```

But that requires me to either

1. know ahead of time what the type of the function is
2. do some sort of pattern match that accounts for *every possible type*.

Is there some way I can find out the type of the object stored as `Any` and convert it to that type?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. The objects a collections stores should be homogeneous. What argues against multiple implementations of Map, like `unaryOps`, `binaryOps` and so on?

Comment: Antoras: agreed, this is poor functional programming. Sometimes I ask questions because I'm curious.

Comment: The clue that this is simply something you should not be doing is the "Any" that is required. Capture the variation in your data structure in the type system (as with the Either example below).

Comment: It's a bad idea to store functions of different types in the same collection. When you pull one out, what do you plan on doing with it? You have no idea what its type is, so you *can't* do anything with it. Consider bundling your functions in a less generic way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this certainly is not a good idea, if you *really* have to do it, you can do it using reflection.

Using PaulP's [Invocation](http://harrah.github.com/browse/samples/library/scala/reflect/Invocation.scala.html) utility:

```
scala> val add: (Int, Int) => Int = _ + _
add: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> val isOdd: Int => Boolean = _ % 2 != 0
isOdd: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> import Invocation._
import Invocation._

scala> val funcs = Map("add" -> add, "isOdd" -> isOdd)
funcs: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,ScalaObject] = Map(add -> <function2>, isOdd -> <function1>)

scala> funcs("add") o 'apply(3, 4)
res18: Any = 7

scala> funcs("isOdd") o 'apply(11)
res19: Any = true
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there some way I can find out the type of the object stored as Any and convert it to that type?

This doesn't actually make sense. Lets suppose I could do it, and it looks like this:

```
val func = funcs(func_name).toAppropriateType
```

Now what?

`func` now holds a value of some unknown type. I can call it... but I don't know its signature, so what arguments do I pass it? And the type/signature is going to be different on every invocation (depending on what was pulled out of the map), so the code to call it is going to have to be different for every invocation; I need some way of having different code executed for each possibility of `func`... but that would be a pattern match! And it would have to account for every possible type, just as match on `Any`.

In fact, the magical `toAppropriateType` method, even if it could exist, gains me **nothing** on top of just using an `Any`. It's still the case that the only things I can do with `func` are things you can do with all values of **every possible type** (i.e. very little).

In general, when you take something out of a collection you have to handle it with code that is valid for **anything that the type allows to be put into the collection**. The only alternative is to use features such as `asInstanceOf`, which throws away the guarantees of the type system and puts the responsibility for ensuring that you don't use the wrong type on you; meaning you have to have some other way of knowing what type to expect, outside of the type system.

If you want to have a collection of functions with one of a pre-determined set of signatures then the best way is to construct a type that only allows those signatures, and allows you to tell the difference between them (such as Rex Kerr's suggestion of using `Either`). Switching to using `Any` as soon as you find you need to combine things of different types in a collection usually causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: I ended up making my own ADT. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could store them in an `Either`:

```
val funcs = Map[String, Either[Int=>Boolean, (Int,Int)=>Int]](
  "add" -> Right(add),
  "odd" -> Left(odd)
)
```

Now you can pull them apart again, though pattern matching is finicky here (`Right(f)` will work, but don't try to put conditions on what `f` is).  I suggest using `fold`, `right`, `left` (and `isRight` and `isLeft` if you really must), like so:

```
def doSomething(s: String) =
  funcs(s).fold(
    f => { f(4) },      // Left is Int=>Boolean
    g => { g(3,5)==8 }  // Right is (Int,Int)=>Int
  )
```

Presumably you'd want some way to load appropriate arguments also instead of the dummy values I put in.

If you have many variants of functions, you can define your own either-like hierarchy except with more different cases, or you can nest `Either`s.

Comment: This approach would still mean I have to enumerate every function type. For functions from one to four+ parameters, with the parameters being anything from `{Int, Float, String, Boolean, MyClass...}` this would get messy very quickly.

Comment: Pattern matching works fine for this example; the compiler can correctly infer the function types because you never throw away the type information. Try it!

Comment: Vlad - if you don't actually know the type of the function that you're retrieving, how do you expect to be able to call it? If the set of signatures is finite (which I can't imagine how it wouldn't be) then you can capture that in your own algebraic data type.

Comment: @Vlad: How do you think you're going to call a function of any type and any number of parameters without enumerating all the possibilities?

Comment: @KrisNuttycombe - Pattern matching is finicky.  You can get it to work if you `Left(f)`, but if you try to remind the compiler of what it already knows `f` is, you then get a bunch of unchecked warnings.

Comment: @KrisNuttycombe - Updated my answer to make this clearer in the main text.